# Not able to add testers to Test Flight when app is under review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

After submitting the app to for review, I'am not able to add new testers or new test groups to the build. On clicking the add button in the Test Flight tab under the build in App Store connect a pop up is displayed with message **"You can only submit one build from version 1.9.5 to Beta App Review".** [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than App Store Connect users a build that is under review cannot be made available to any testers. Although the error message is not very clear you can't add external users to a build that is not approved. Once it is approved you will be able to add new groups of users to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Internal or External Testing capabilities in https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ and find out what is going wrong with your case.